True False boolean not recognized?
How is it possible that a True or False boolean is not recognized as such?
print(f"before {self.reverse_maze}")
if self.reverse_maze:
    print(f"after {self.reverse_maze}")

output is this:
before False
after False

I tried using if not and that stopped the 2nd output 'after', but 'if' should be True then how it is possible that 'after' statement would be printing has me at a loss

Try print(type(self.reverse_maze))

print(f"before {self.reverse_maze!r}") — Look at a repr with the !r parameter, that should make things clearer.

self.reverse_maze could be the string "False". Such a string is a truth-y, and it will provide the output you're seeing.
